# Webpack - ReferenceError: global is not defined, in next13

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, configuration, next.js13

While working on a NextJS 13 app, I countered this error:
`ReferenceError: global is not defined`

I searched for the error and found some solutions, but they didn't work.
I tried to change the configuration file and tried also to trace the error, but none of this worked for me.

This is my NextJS config file

```js
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  pageExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'mdx'],
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
    mdxRs: true,
  },
  sassOptions: {
    prependData: `
@import "styles/theme.scss";
@import "styles/mixins.scss";
    `,
  },
  webpack: (config, {isServer}, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.mdx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: '@mdx-js/loader',
            /** @type {import('@mdx-js/loader').Options} */
            options: {...options},
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.ya?ml$/,
        oneOf: [
          {
            resourceQuery: /stream/,
            options: {asStream: true},
            loader: 'yaml-loader',
          },
          {loader: 'yaml-loader'},
        ],
      }
    );
    if (!isServer) {
      config.resolve.fallback = {
        fs: false,
      };
    }
    config.infrastructureLogging = {
      level: 'error',
    };
    return config;
  },
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: '/home',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

This is the error:
[image: error, in Chrome]

## EDIT

I found that this error is caused by importing functions from the `utils` directory where I put my utility functions, and using them inside client-side components.
And now the issue is that I can't put `'use client'` in my utility functions file, which also causes errors in the server-side components.
I tried to make two files for the utility functions, one for the client-side and one for the server-side but that also didn't work.

Is there a better, more intuitive solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you also use turborepo. The Prisma has this guide, that using `globalThis`. Basically the idea is similar to using `global`, but because the `global` only available at `node` environment, we have to use `globalThis` instead.

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const prismaClientSingleton = () => {
  return new PrismaClient()
}

type PrismaClientSingleton = ReturnType<typeof prismaClientSingleton>

const globalForPrisma = globalThis as unknown as {
  prisma: PrismaClientSingleton | undefined
}

const prisma = globalForPrisma.prisma ?? prismaClientSingleton()

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') globalForPrisma.prisma = prisma

export default prisma
```

Source: https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/other/troubleshooting-orm/help-articles/nextjs-prisma-client-dev-practices